# Find series for spiraling over matrix of size $nxn$ filled with numbers from 1 up till and including $n^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, elementary-number-theory

The following question exists:

> When starting from the number 1 and adding four numbers on each row a $4x4$ matrix is formed as follows:
>
> \begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\5&6&7&8\\9&10&11&12\\13&14&15&16\end{bmatrix}
>
> Starting from the upper left and spiralling inwards in a clockwise direction the following series is obtained: $1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 16, 15, 14, 13, 9, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10$.
>
> Create a method spiral that finds the spiraling series for a $nxn$ matrix.

I am looking for a mathematical series to capture this logic.

What I see is that the first row is an exception. There we have $n$ elements in the series $1, 2, 3, ...$. Next we get sets of 2 of respectively length $n-1, n-2, n-3, ...$.

We can describe the right column (without the one upper left element taken in the previous slice) as $2n, 3n, ..$. The next time we arrive there (7, 11 above) it will be $2n-1, 3n-1, ...$. The lower row can be described as $n*n-1, n*2-2, n*2-3, ...$ and the next time (10 above) it will be $n*(n-1)-2, ...$. And last but not least the upwards directions will first be (9, 5 above) something like $2n+1, n+1, ...$ and then (not visible above).

Is there proper logic to capture this series? If so, can someone be so kind to tell me how to formalize this properly?

/edit: One other way to look at it is as repeatedly rotating a matrix to the left (transpose and then reverse columns) and cutting off the top. For this I also don't know how to formalize it.